# Composer install: your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: bolt-cms

Trying to install Bolt v2.2.4 with the following commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/bolt/bolt.git bolt
cd bolt
git checkout v2.2.4
composer install
```

Then I get the following error:

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for m6web/symfony2-coding-standard dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by m6web/symfony2-coding-standard[dev-master].
    - m6web/symfony2-coding-standard dev-master requires squizlabs/php_codesniffer ~1.0 -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue under bolt 2.1.9

I 'fixed' it for me for the moment by changing `1.5.*` to `~2` for `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Are you on IPv6 per chance? If so, do a `composer self-update`.